# Find nearest keyframe using scales

Tags: d3.js

I have a linear scale that is a mapping between screen pixels and frames (0-100)

```
const frameScale = scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 1000]) // pixels
  .range([0, 100]) // frames
  .clamp(true);
```

I now want to have a scale that contains an arbitrary number of key frames

```
const keyScale = scale***()
  .domain([5, 25, 60, 88]) // key frames
  .range([0, 100]);
```

I want to be able to from either a pixel value or from a frame determine the closest keyframe.

What scale should the keyframes be defined in?

And what functions should I use to convert from px -> closest keyframe
and frame -> keyframe?

**Update:**
Here is a playground to see what I'm trying to do.
https://beta.observablehq.com/@leon/key-frame-scales

Using `scaleQuantize` gives something, but it's not correct as you can see it outputs keyframe 50 much to far to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a pre built scale that worked.

What I ended up doing was first using the frameScale to get the current frame.

and then using this function to get the closest keyframe

```
const currentFrame = this.frameScale(x);

const keyframes = [10, 20, 30];

const closestFrame = closestKeyFrame(keyframes, currentFrame);

const closestKeyFrame = (keyframes, frame) => {
    return keyframes.reduce((prev, curr) => Math.abs(curr - frame) < Math.abs(prev - frame) ? curr : prev);
}
```